Strong convexity and Lipschitz-continuous gradients, how restrictive are these assumptions in practice?
I am reading a paper on stochastic gradient descent and different varieties of it. For all the convergence proofs the author assumes strong convexity and Lipschitz-continuous gradients  for the objective function. I have seen the same assumptions in other papers too when analyzing different optimization algorithms.
I am asking myself how useful all the convergence results are with such possibly restrictive assumptions? I would assume that most of the time one doesn't have strong convexity and/or Lipschitz-continuous gradients.

Welcome to the club, where people are bothered by the restrictive assumptions in convergence. Please distinguish between (solely) convergence and the rate of the convergence results. Usually establishing the rate of convergence requires restrictive assumptions which is not the case for convergence (without establishing the rate). For example, you can show that the gradient descent converges for all twice differentiable functions which are bounded below. The latter is not restrictive.
